# ClearDB with Heroku - Cannot access DB

Tags: cleardb

I have updated my ClearDB and since that time, I cannot connect to my DB. I really need help. I have created a ticket on Heroku since 24 hours and I am still waiting.
Tk in advance

I have updating my ClearDB plan to fix the max of users and since that time, I cannot reach the BD